# Problem with dual boot(14.04&8.1); Windows 8.1 not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my windows 8.1 machine using bootable USB. while installing I selected the same drive where windows is installed and got Ubuntu installed. after installation I can see windows entry while booting but after selecting windows 8 from that menu nothing happens, a cursor keeps on blinking and finally nothing happens.

Now I am unable to boot into windows.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: When booted in Ubuntu, can you share your disk layout (`sudo fdisk -l` or printscreen of `gparted`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, as my BIOS is UEFI (new PCs have this):

1- I created the bootable pendrive with windows 8.1 with GPT for UEFI BIOS. 
2- reinstall windows 8.1, I created two partitions on my HD, one for windoes and the other as free space (this will be used as linux partiion), windows installer creates several extra partition to install de boot, etc. after that windows 8.1 is installed.

3- reboot the system and boot with your linux pendrive.
4- When the installation of linux shows the partition where you want to install the OS, you have to create a partition for boot as ext4 in /boot, and another partition in / , to install the OS with ext4, and another partition for swap. you can choose these option easily in the installation screen.

5 Install

I hope it helps.